# Read data from ttyUSB port

Tags: android, file, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a USB TO Serial Adapter. The way I do it is with a FileReader directed to the ttyUSB0 file. The problem is that every time i recieve a byte/char on the android tablet, the android tablet reads the byte/char and then sends the same byte/char back to the Adapter.

The other issue that I am facing, is that until i send the byte "4" on the line, the FileReader refuses to close the connection and to stop recieving data(even though it has already filled up it's buffer)

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please try to provide a sample code and possible related stacktrace in your question. That way your question gets more attention.